# pass data from Rails to javascript in my case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My controller:

```
class SchoolController < ApplicationController

  def index
    ...
  end

  def edit
    @school=School.find_by_id params[:id]

  end

  def check_teachers
    @teachers = @school.teachers

    #How to show teachers' names and titles in a lightbox by javascript ?

  end

end
```

As you see above, I have a `check_teachers` method, inside which I got a list of teachers objects. Each `Teacher` object has `name` and `title` attributes.

A **button** click on the **view** will trigger the `check_teachers` method get called:

I would like to show all teachers `name` and `title` in a lightbox. I think I would need **javascript** to implement this. But I don't know how can I pass all the teachers' data from **Rails** to **javascript** and show the data in a js implemented lightbox...

Anyone can provide any help on this?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with ajax. Simpliest way is to use FancyBox(jquery plugin, http://fancybox.net/home )

your button code should looks like

`<a id="ajax_button" href="<%= url_for :controller => :school, :action =>:check_teachers, :id=>@school.id %>">Check teachers</a>`

then add this javascript

`$(document).bind('load', function() { $("#various3").fancybox({ajax:{type : "GET" } })`

and your method controller action should looks like

`def check_teachers

@school = School.find(params[:id])

    @teachers = @school.teachers

end`

but it's better to move `@school = School.find(params[:id])` to before_filter